# How to add to a Date in Elixir Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I need to store `today + 1 day` in an Ecto.DateTime variable for storing in a database, but for the life of me I can't find how to do that. The Timex library is popular in Elixir, and in older versions I found a `Timex.Date.add()` but that is gone in the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `timex` 3.0, you can use `Timex.add/2` and `Timex.Duration.from_days/1`:

```
iex(1)> Ecto.DateTime.utc
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-25 14:47:07>
iex(2)> Timex.add(Timex.now, Timex.Duration.from_days(1)) |> Ecto.DateTime.cast!
#Ecto.DateTime<2016-12-26 14:47:08.996803>
```